# Install header files respecting subdirectories with CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a set of header files under several subdirectories

```
|- A
| | - a.h
| | - b.h
| | - a.cpp
| | - b.cpp
|
| B
  | - c.h
  | - d.h
  | - c.cpp
  | - d.cpp
```

I have a variable with the paths of each file

```
set(HEADERS A/a.h A/b.h B/c.h B/d.h)
```

and I populate the PUBLIC_HEADER property of a target with that variable and install it using

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget
    PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}"
    )
install(TARGETS MyTarget
        PUBLIC_HEADER
          DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyTarget/

)
```

The issue is that is doesn't respect the subdirectories and the four files are installed under `MyTarget`. I would like to install them under `MyTarget/A` for `a.h` and `b.h` and under `MyTarget/B` for `c.h` and `d.h`.

Answer (score 1):

If your header directory (e.g. `include`) above `A` and `B` contains installable headers you could do

```
install(DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyTarget
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
    PATTERN "*_p.h" EXCLUDE
)
```

The trailing slash on the `include` directory denotes that its contents (including its structure) is copied to the destination.

Otherwise the headers can be installed manually for each directory as follows.

```
set(HEADERS_A A/a.h A/b.h)
set(HEADERS_B B/c.h B/d.h)
install(FILES ${HEADERS_A} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyTarget/A)
install(FILES ${HEADERS_B} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyTarget/B)
```

Comment: The directory contains also the sources and non installable headers

Comment: Do the non installable headers follow a certain naming scheme? Then you could exclude them by a  `FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"` pattern. Otherwise you need to install them one by one.

Comment: Yes, they follow a naming scheme. Actually, I also install them, but in another directory `_p.h`.

Comment: I updated the example to exclude the internal headers.